# Linux auth server creation

Tags: linux, authentication, samba

How can I create a Samba PDC on a Linux server that authenticates Windows and Linux with the same password? I'm thinking either an LDAP backend that propagates to both, or some way to synchronize Samba and Linux passwords with PAM, but I have no idea what is best.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the question...if you mean you want to have windows and linux clients to log in to the same samba PDC then you might find this link helpful

-> [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAP-Samba_PDC_%28for_Linux_and_Windows%29) <-

Hope that helps.

Oh but its not  a supported guide so use at your own risk

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to use Samba to create a Windows Domain, then you should use an LDAP backend.  There is a fair amount of Samba configuration to set up a [domain controller](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/samba-pdc.html), though.

Once you have LDAP set up, you can also use it for your PAM backend.  There are of course [some options](http://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/PAM) for how to do this.

Of course, if you already have a windows domain (Active Directory), then you merely need to use that as your LDAP backend, and you don't need to make your Samba server a domain controller, just a domain member.